# Print comments of files in a zip ordered in lines, Python

Tags: python, zip

this is the thing. I have to make a program which will begin by reading a file in a zip, in that file it will find the name of the .txt file to read next, and so it goes on, until it reaches a file without the name of the following one, so it just prints the content.

I did it and works perfectly, however, after it reads all the files, I need the program to print the comment of every single file read, so it will supposedly print an ascii art.

There's where I have trouble. What I did is to append every single comment during the loop in a list, and at the end I map the list to a string and join them.

This is my code:

```
import zipfile
import re

nothing_var = "90052"
text = ".txt"
list_files = []
list_comments = []

with zipfile.ZipFile("channel.zip") as file:
    count = len(file.infolist()) - 1
    for var1 in range(count):
        list_comments.append(file.getinfo(str(nothing_var) + ".txt").comment)
        with file.open(str(nothing_var) + ".txt") as archive:
            for line in archive:
                if re.search("\d+", str(line)):
                    nothing_var = re.findall("\d+", str(line))
                    nothing_var = "".join(nothing_var)
                    list_files.append(nothing_var)
                else:
                    print(line)

list_comments = list(map(str, list_comments))

print("".join(list_comments))
```

And this is the output I get:

```
b'Collect the comments.'
b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'\n'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'\n'b'*'b'*'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b'*'b'*'b'\n'b'*'b'*'b' 'b' 'b' 'b'O'b'O'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b'O'b'O'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b'X'b'X'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b'Y'b'Y'b'Y'b'Y'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b'G'b'G'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b'G'b'G'b' 'b' 'b'E'b'E'b'E'b'E'b'E'b'E'b' 'b'N'b'N'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b'N'b'N'b' 'b' 'b'*'b'*'b'\n'b'*'b'*'b' 'b' 'b' 'b'O'b'O'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b'O'b'O'b' 'b' 'b'X'b'X'b'X'b'X'b'X'b'X'b' 'b' 'b' 'b'Y'b'Y'b'Y'b'Y'b'Y'b'Y'b' 'b' 'b' 'b'G'b'G'b' 'b' 'b' 'b'G'b'G'b' 'b' 'b' 'b'E'b'E'b'E'b'E'b'E'b'E'b' 'b' 'b'N'b'N'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b'N'b'N'b' 'b' 'b' 'b'*'b'*'b'\n'b'*'b'*'b' 'b' 'b' 'b'O'b'O'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b'O'b'O'b' 'b'X'b'X'b'X'b' 'b' 'b'X'b'X'b'X'b' 'b'Y'b'Y'b'Y'b' 'b' 'b' 'b'Y'b'Y'b' 'b' 'b'G'b'G'b' 'b'G'b'G'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b'E'b'E'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b'N'b'N'b' 'b' 'b'N'b'N'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b'*'b'*'b'\n'b'*'b'*'b' 'b' 'b' 'b'O'b'O'b'O'b'O'b'O'b'O'b'O'b'O'b' 'b'X'b'X'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b'X'b'X'b' 'b'Y'b'Y'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b'G'b'G'b'G'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b'E'b'E'b'E'b'E'b'E'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b'N'b'N'b'N'b'N'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b'*'b'*'b'\n'b'*'b'*'b' 'b' 'b' 'b'O'b'O'b'O'b'O'b'O'b'O'b'O'b'O'b' 'b'X'b'X'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b'X'b'X'b' 'b'Y'b'Y'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b'G'b'G'b'G'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b'E'b'E'b'E'b'E'b'E'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b'N'b'N'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b'*'b'*'b'\n'b'*'b'*'b' 'b' 'b' 'b'O'b'O'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b'O'b'O'b' 'b'X'b'X'b'X'b' 'b' 'b'X'b'X'b'X'b' 'b'Y'b'Y'b'Y'b' 'b' 'b' 'b'Y'b'Y'b' 'b' 'b'G'b'G'b' 'b'G'b'G'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b'E'b'E'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b'N'b'N'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b'*'b'*'b'\n'b'*'b'*'b' 'b' 'b' 'b'O'b'O'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b'O'b'O'b' 'b' 'b'X'b'X'b'X'b'X'b'X'b'X'b' 'b' 'b' 'b'Y'b'Y'b'Y'b'Y'b'Y'b'Y'b' 'b' 'b' 'b'G'b'G'b' 'b' 'b' 'b'G'b'G'b' 'b' 'b' 'b'E'b'E'b'E'b'E'b'E'b'E'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b'N'b'N'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b'*'b'*'b'\n'b'*'b'*'b' 'b' 'b' 'b'O'b'O'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b'O'b'O'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b'X'b'X'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b'Y'b'Y'b'Y'b'Y'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b'G'b'G'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b'G'b'G'b' 'b' 'b'E'b'E'b'E'b'E'b'E'b'E'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b'N'b'N'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b'*'b'*'b'\n'b'*'b'*'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b' 'b'*'b'*'b'\n'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'\n'b' 'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'*'b'\n'
```

(Sorry for writing the complete output)

The first line is the content of the last file read, it's ok.

What I want is to take off the b' ' from each comment just leavig the letter, symbol or space in between. And to print the comments in lines just separating them each time there's a \n in the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `b'...'` before the character means that it is a byte string. You need to decode it to produce a string:

```
>>> b"abcde".decode("utf-8") 
'abcde'
```

Comment: Completely fixed my problem. Thank you