# Reading multiple zip archive comments with python

Tags: python, archive, zip

My zip file contains a lot of smaller zip files.

I want to iterate through all those files, 
reading and printing each of their comments.

I've found out that  `zipfile file.zip` or `unzip -z file.zip`can do this to a file in separate, but I'm looking for a way to go through all of them.

Couldn't find anything perfect yet, but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38273849/print-comments-of-files-in-a-zip-ordered-in-lines-python) post. However, the code is too advanced for me, and I need something very basic, to begin with :)

Any ideas or information would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure exactly what your looking for but here are a few ways I did it on an Ubuntu Linux machine.

```
for i in `ls *.zip`; do unzip -l $i; done
```

or

```
unzip -l myzip.zip
```

or

```
unzip -p myzip.zip | python -c 'import zipfile,sys,StringIO;print     "\n".join(zipfile.ZipFile(StringIO.StringIO(sys.stdin.read())).namelist())'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the zipfile library to iterate through your files and
get their comments using zipinfo.comment

```
import zipfile

file = zipfile.ZipFile('filepath.zip')

infolist = file.infolist()
    for info in infolist:
        print(info.comment)
```

The example above prints the comment of each file in your zip file.

You could loop through your zip files and print their contents comments similiarly.

Check out the [official zipfile documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipInfo), its super clear.

Answer (score 0):

A short and easy way to achieve this:

```py
from zipfile import ZipFile

ziplist = ZipFile('parentzip.zip').namelist()

for childzip in ziplist:
    zip_comment = ZipFile(childzip).comment
```

Reminder that if you want to do string based comparisons you should either encode your reference string as bytes, or convert the comment into a string. Ex:

```py
from zipfile import ZipFile

paths = ['file1.zip', 'file2.zip', 'file3.zip']

bad_str = 'please ignore me'
new = []
for filename in paths:
    zip_comment = zipfile.ZipFile(filename).comment
    if not zip_comment == str.encode(bad_str):
        new.append(filename)

paths = new
```